# How to make complex queries (including orderBy, whereIn and isNotEqualTo) from Cloud Firestore with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

### **Main question**

I am making a social media app which recommends posts to users. The posts have fields `user`, `gym` and `grade`, all of which are of type `String`. `user` refers to the user that made the post.

I want to recommend posts which have `gym` and `grade` that are found in lists of preferred gyms and grades, so I want to use `whereIn` on those fields. However, I do NOT want to recommend posts that were posted by the user of the app (i.e. I don't want users to see their own posts in their recommended posts), so I want to use `isNotEqualTo` on the `user` field.

Additionally, the posts have a `timestamp` field. I want to recommend the latest posts, so I want to use `orderBy` on the `timestamp` field.

Lastly, I only want to load 10 posts at a time, so I want to use `limit(10)`.

However, I have to load the next 10 posts when the user scrolls past 10 posts, so I want to use `startAfterDocument` for that.

So this is what I attempted:

A possible `searchTerms` looks like this:

```
final searchTerms = {
  'notUser': 'nathantew',
  'gyms': ['gym1','gym2'],
  'grades': ['grade1','grade2'],
}
```

Then the query using `searchTerms` (the actual query logic is longer in my code as the posts have more fields, and I attempted to make a generalised query function. I extracted the relevant parts):

```dart
var query =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').orderBy('timestamp');
if (lastDoc != null) {
  query = query.startAfterDocument(lastDoc);
}
if (searchTerms['notUser'] != null) {
  query = query.where('user', isNotEqualTo: searchTerms['notUser']);
}
if (searchTerms['gyms'] != null) {
  query = query.where('gym', whereIn: searchTerms['gyms']);
}
if (searchTerms['grades'] != null) {
  query = query.where('grade', whereIn: searchTerms['grades']);
}
return query.limit(10).get();
```

However, that throws an error on the `isNotEqualTo` filter:

> _AssertionError ('package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 677 pos 11: 'field == orders[0][0]': The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([timestamp]), false]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where() field parameter 'FieldPath([user])' when an inequality operator is invoked.)

### **Extra questions and things I tried**

I doubt this is how queries actually work for a non-SQL database like cloud firestore, but the way I imagine the query is that the posts are first ordered by `timestamp`, then we iterate through the posts from newest to oldest, then whichever post has a `gym` and `grade` in the list of preferred gyms and grades, AND doesn't have a `user` which is `'nathantew'`, will be added to the list of documents that will be returned to the app when the list reaches 10 documents.

And this way, when I request for the next 10 posts, I can pass in the last document of the previous query and start from there.

I tried searching up the error, but it seems to me that my understanding of how queries happen is completely wrong, because I quickly found a confusingly large amount of rules restricting how queries can be made.

The rules are confusing too, for example, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations states "If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field". Also, "You cannot order your query by any field included in an equality (=) or in clause." I'm using `isNotEqualTo` in this case, so does that fall under the first rule, or the second? It doesn't seem like `isNotEqualTo` is a "range comparison" filter, but the error called on the `isNotEqualTo` sounds like it is referring to the first rule...

I've seen suggestions to make a less complicated query omitting certain filters, and only add the filters in the local app code. I don't know how that'll work.

I can't omit the `orderBy` `timestamp` query filter or I would have to query the entire database to filter it locally.

But if I omit any of the `where` filters, then I need to query an unknown number of documents each time to ensure 10 documents are queried that satisfy the conditions.

And the more I think about it, the more possible errors I imagine. What if a user deletes their post as I am trying to use that document for the `startAfterDocument` filter...?

So, how should I make this query? Even better, where can I find best practices for such use cases? Are they all hidden from amateurs as they are used by large companies with professionals?

Comment: There are way too many questions in this post for a valid question on Stack Overflow.  Narrow it down to just a single question, and you will be far more likely to get an answer.  If you don't, it is likely to get closed with "needs focus" as the reason.

Comment: @DougStevenson okay I guess I’ll ask other smaller questions.